# JPQL Query for joining Txn table with Account only using records with maximum value of date

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql, jpa-2.1

I have a table Account{accId, accNo,.... so on},
I also have another table Txn{txnId,accId,CR_DR,txnAmt,txnDate,...so on}
Txn may contain multiple records for each Account.

I want to join only **latest** Txn record with CR_DR="C" of each Account, along with that Account using accId.

I want to do this using JPQL can anyone please suggest a query.

Answer (score 0):

When combining entities in JPQL, you must map every joining link to allow relation traversal. To do so, the mapping must reflect the most common relationships that may be desired in queries.

In your case, I assume your Account entity has a @OneToMany mapping to Txn transactions and the corresponding @ManyToOne mapping from Txn to Account. So, your first JPQL may be written as:

```
SELECT txn FROM Txn AS txn WHERE txn.account = :acct AND txn.crdr = :crdr
```

This query will return all transactions of the given :acct and :crdr as a list.

Provided your txnDate field may be ordered, you can order the list by date and limit the result using ORDER BY and LIMIT JPQL statements:

```
SELECT txn FROM Txn AS txn WHERE txn.account = :acct AND txn.crdr = :crdr ORDER BY txn.txnDate DESC LIMIT 1
```

As Txn has a @ManyToOne mapping to account, the result, if existent, will allow you to retrieve all EAGERLY loaded properties of Txn, so account can be accessed from it.